# How to change the PostGIS schema in raster2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I was sucessfull when I used this mode to store Raster in Postgis (**raster2pgsql.exe**):

C: \ Program Files \ PostgreSQL \ 9.4 \ bin>
Raster2pgsql.exe -s 32373 -I -C -M
C: \ Users \ Geo \ Raster \ Stockpile.jp2
-F -t 100x100 **Stockpile_MRM** |
Psql -U postgres -d GEOSURVEY -h 192.168.1.14 -p 5432

But it goes directly to the **public** schema.
I used this mode to change the schema (**schema_name.table**), but it does not work. I saw in - http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/using_raster_dataman.html, but nothing changes.

C: \ Program Files \ PostgreSQL \ 9.4 \ bin>
Raster2pgsql.exe -s 32373 -I -C -M
C: \ Users \ Geo \ Raster \ Stockpile.jp2
-F -t 100x100 **BD_Maputo.Stockpile** |
Psql -U postgres -d GEOSURVEY -h 192.168.1.14 -p 5432

[image]

**what i´m doing wrong here?**

Comment: Did you try putting BD_Maputo.Stockpile between double quotes?

Comment: I did not! I will try ...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and adding double quotes didn't work for me.  What solved it in the end was setting the schema search path for the whole database:

```
alter database <database_name> set search_path = <schema_name>,public
```

And then running raster2pgsql using `<schema_name>.<table_name>` to reference the table:

```
raster2pgsql.exe -s 32373 -I -C -M C: \ Users \ Geo \ Raster \ Stockpile.jp2 -F -t 100x100 BD_Maputo.Stockpile
```

Comment: How do you specify a quoted schema? `"09-my-unusual-schema".table_name`?

Comment: Ah. I see that the output of the raster2pgsql command always is quoted. And the trick is getting the schema to be in the database search path